# Not all contacts from entry Data Extension evaluated in Journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have a very simple journey with a Data Extension entry source with around 290,000 records, each corresponding to one contact. The Data Extension has a correct Subscriber Key relationship (Salesforce originating PersonContactId mapped to Subscriber Key). It has no filter limiting entry, no decision splits, is set to re-entry anytime and was scheduled to run only once. It uses the Email from Entry Source as the Email for the send.

Out of 290,000 contacts, only 141,500 Contacts have been evaluated for entry. What could be the reason? A few contacts out of these could be SFMC unsubscribed but definitely not the whole missing 150k.

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be the High Water Mark. To understand the concept better, you can read more [here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A8wi3SAB), [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/109059/re-entering-a-journey-journey-builder-sfmc/110313) and [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/303077/how-to-bypass-high-water-mark-in-marketing-cloud-journey-builder).

There are two things that might prevent it from stopping your contacts to enter the Journey (of course considering you have selected `re-entry anytime` option):

1. [Contact Evaluation Settings](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_manage_audience_data.htm&type=5) inside the Journey:

   - `Evaluate new records only` - only new records get evaluated that already passed   High Water Mark.
   - `Evaluate all records` - all contacts get evaluated in the Entry Source DE.
2. Set the schedule of the Journey related to the [Automation'schedule](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_schedule_a_data_extension_entry_source.htm&type=5), which will have an SQL that will overwrite the Entry Source DE and thus bypass High Water Mark.