# Is journey builder picking up new contacts added after activation from a data extension?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions

I create a single send journey and selected as entry source a data extension.

I can see I have 200 contacts then I activate the journey and all those 200 contacts went through it.

However, I added once the journey has been activated one contact to the data extension.

I can see in the record count 201 contacts, however that contact doesn't go in.

Is this working as designed? How can I perform changes in the data extension and keep inserting the contacts in the journey without creating a new version?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single Send Journey does not have a recurring schedule, which means it will push Entry Source contacts only once per journey's activation or at the specific time, you can set.

You would need to configure Multi-Step Journey to allow more people to enter the journey later on. In this type of journey, you can choose between a recurring schedule and automation and both options can result in pushing contacts into the journey more than once, however you need to also configure a correct Contact Entry setting and "Evaluate all records" within the schedule if the same contacts should be eligible for re-entry.

Additional sources:

1. [Single Send Journeys](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_manage_single_send.htm&type=5)
2. [Contact Entry Settings](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_journey_settings.htm&type=5)
3. [High Water Mark concept for journey re-entry](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/109059/re-entering-a-journey-journey-builder-sfmc)
4. [Choose How to Process Entry Source Data](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_manage_audience_data.htm&type=5)